# docker-compose trying to run sh script (npm / ng serve) but cannot find directory

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, angular-cli

I have this part on the `docker-compose` that will copy the `angular-cli` frontend and a `scripts` directory.

```
  www:
    build: ./www
    volumes:
      - ./www/frontend:/app
      - ./www/scripts:/scripts
    command: /scripts/init-dev.sh
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "49153:49153"
```

The `Dockerfile` inside the `www` will install npm.

```
FROM node:10-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache git make curl gcc g++ python2

RUN npm config set user 0
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

RUN npm install
```

And the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Serving.."
cd /app && npm run-script start
```

I'm running the `docker-compose down && docker-compose build && docker-compose up` command:

```
www_1       | standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I assume the error comes from the `command` line.

Comment: Are you on a Windows host?  Does the Alpine-based container actually have `bash`, or does it use a lighter-weight POSIX shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're doing it in the wrong order.

I'm not an expert in Node but you needs a package.json or whatever for npm install to do the job. I guess it's in /app. But at build time, /app is nowhere to be seen since it's not mentionned in Dockerfile.

Try moving `npm install` in the script, `cd /app && npm install && npm run-script start`.

Answer (score 1):

Have had a similar issue, you might try adding `execute` privileges to this file

```
chmod +x www/scripts/init-dev.sh
```